# Xamarin.Android i am getting Soap Service time out exception on my mobile phone

Tags: android, web-services, xamarin, soap, xamarin.android

My main purpose is getting data from soap webservice on my android phone. Actually i implemented webservice references correctly. But i want to try some data from soap webservice on my android phone , i am getting time out exception like this ;

**System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out.**

Here is my source code ;

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        var service = new LifeService.LifeService();
        var result = service.LifeService_getPersons("xxx@gmail.com","12345");
    }
```

After adding some email and number to the LifeService_getPersons method it should return PersonList to me . Nevertheless it return an exception what i mentioned above. I run this service at windows form application and xamarin.android by using an emulator. Service works fine . It returns data correctly. However when i try to use it on my self phone , it is not working. Then i thought it might be some permission problem and added permissions to the Manifest.xml file such as ;

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Unfortunately it doesn't change anything.Please help . thanks.

Comment: Yes , it is public .

Comment: Maybe  the operation took too long to complete on your real device because of network environment . You could set the `TimeOut` manually . Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.timeout?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_WebRequest_Timeout

Comment: i think there is some problem about my android phone . Because emulator work fine . But i dont understand what it is . I added timeout manually .Nothing changed :(

Comment: You could debug it on another device .

Comment: @Bora.Ozgur I have the same problem. Managed to solve?